# Checking the difference between old and new XML

Tags: c++, performance, xml

I have two xml files, about 500mb each, an old and a new. I want to find out what items have been added or removed in the new.xml compared with the old.xml.

I had some help on this code and I'm a bit new to C++ but I was wondering if this is the optimal way to approach a problem such as this.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include "include/pugixml.hpp"

#define con(m) std::cout << m << '\n'
#define err(m) std::cerr << m << std::endl

using str_set = std::set<std::string>;

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;

    str_set a;
    doc.load_file("old.xml");

    // fill set a with just the ids from file a
    for(auto&& node: doc.child("site_entries").children("entry"))
        a.emplace(node.child("id").text().as_string());

    str_set b;
    doc.load_file("new.xml");

    // fill set b with just the ids from file b
    for(auto&& node: doc.child("site_entries").children("entry"))
        b.emplace(node.child("id").text().as_string());

    // now use the <algorithms> library

    str_set b_from_a;
    std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()
        , std::inserter(b_from_a, b_from_a.begin()));

    str_set a_from_b;
    std::set_difference(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end()
        , std::inserter(a_from_b, a_from_b.begin()));

    str_set a_and_b;
    std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()
        , std::inserter(a_and_b, a_and_b.begin()));

    for(auto&& v: a)
        con("a       : " << v);

    con("");

    for(auto&& v: b)
        con("b       : " << v);

    con("");

    for(auto&& v: b_from_a)
        con("b_from_a: " << v);

    con("");

    for(auto&& v: a_from_b)
        con("a_from_b: " << v);

    con("");

    for(auto&& v: a_and_b)
        con("a_and_b : " << v);

    con("");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code seems simple and how it works is clear enough. I only have a few remarks:

- This line seems a little bit off:

  ```
  #include "include/pugixml.hpp"
  ```

  Generally speaking, in C and C++, libraries provide an `include` dir that has to be added to the search directories so that we can write:

  ```
  #include "pugixml.hpp"
  ```

  While it certainly does not make your code invalid, it makes it feel a bit less pedantic.
- Your code currently does not handle parsing errors. See [pugi's documentation](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/manual/loading.html#manual.loading.errors) for more information about that.
- Now, let's have a look at your set operations. We will use the following diagram to simplify the explanation:

[image: A, B and A ∩ B]

You are currently computing \$A \setminus B\$ and \$B \setminus A\$, then \$A \cap B\$ (where \$A \setminus B\$ represents the difference between \$A\$ and \$B\$). Technically speaking, it would be faster to compute \$A \cap B\$ first then to compute \$A \setminus (A \cap B)\$ and \$B \setminus (A \cap B)\$ since it would mean fewer elements to compare in the sets (there are fewer elements in \$(A \cap B)\$ than there are in \$A\$ or in \$B\$).

In other words, your code should be:

```
str_set a_and_b;
std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()
    , std::inserter(a_and_b, a_and_b.begin()));

str_set b_from_a;
std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), a_and_b.begin(), a_and_b.end()
    , std::inserter(b_from_a, b_from_a.begin()));

str_set a_from_b;
std::set_difference(b.begin(), b.end(), a_and_b.begin(), a_and_b.end()
    , std::inserter(a_from_b, a_from_b.begin()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I understand it all apart from the last point, I'm not quite sure how I would implement that, might you be able to elaborate a tiny bit to help me on my way please?

Comment: @Jimmy Take [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Venn_A_intersect_B.svg/2000px-Venn_A_intersect_B.svg.png). You can see that A without the elements from B is equivalent to A without the element from (A ∩ B). Since you also compute the elements from (A ∩ B), you can get the difference between A and B by computing the difference between A and (A ∩ B) by computing the `std::set_intersection` before the two `std::set_difference`.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm is a shallow comparison between the documents: it is possible that one of the children of site_entries has a corresponding child in the other document (by name), but other changes are present between the two (like subnodes).

Was your intention a shallow comparison algorithm, or is your implementation incomplete?

That said:

```
#define con(m) std::cout << m << '\n'
#define err(m) std::cerr << m << std::endl
```

As a general rule, never use macrodefinitions to write code. In this code, you are better off writing the output code directly. Also, you never use err macro (so you might as well remove it).

You should also refactor this code:

```
for(auto&& v: a_and_b)
    con("a_and_b : " << v);

con("");
```

into this:

```
void print(const std::string& tag, const str_set& ss)
{
    for(const auto& s: ss)
        std::cout << tag << s << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This will shorten the code in main and make it easier to update (because it centralizes the output operation to a single place):

```
int main()
{
    // computation part is the same

    print("a        :", a);
    print("b        :", b);
    print("b_from_a :", b_from_a);
    print("a_from_b :", a_from_b);
    print("a_and_b  :", a_and_b);
}
```